# How to use drop-down menus as filters including an "All" option?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, filtering

I have a list with clients and data about their orders (date, amount ordered, price etc.)
It is named [m]/[year] e.g. 1/23 for January 2023.

I am trying to create a separate sheet with statistics that would give me a better overview of the data in the first sheet. I'd like to sort it by the period, category and location which you can select from a drop-down menu.

[image: Period, Category and Location filters]

I have this piece of code that takes the sheet name from Period and uses the Category and Location filter keywords to sum the totals from all orders corresponding with the selected filters.

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT($A2&"!"&"F2:F");INDIRECT($A2&"!"&"C2:C");$B$2;INDIRECT($A2&"!"&"D2:D");$C$2)
```

This works perfectly. However, I would like to implement an "All" option for the filters too.

[image: Filters with the "All" option selected]

Summing up everything at the same time wouldn't be such a problem, but the filters can have any combination of "All" options selected which adds up to 8 possible combinations between the three filters.

[image: Filters with only a single "All" selected]

**My thought process is to create 8 different branches of SUMIFS nested in an IFS function.**

**Is there a simpler, more elegant way of doing filters in Google Sheets? I am not just looking for t
he solution, I need a pointer in the right direction so that I can read up on it and learn it.**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized example with some sample data to deal with your expected case scenario:

```
=sumif(A:A,if(D2="All","<>All",D2),B:B)
```

[image]